# Elegant way to map a function over the columns of an array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an array

```
data = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

And I want map `Standardize` over the column of the array. I use following code

```
Composition[
  Transpose,
  (Standardize /@ #)&,
  Transpose][data]
```

> ```
> {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}
> ```

Is there a shorter way to get that result?
PS: maybe using of `MapThread`, but function `Standarize` takes a list as input.

**EDIT**

I have picked a bad example. Use this example:

```
data = {{-4, -8, -8}, {-9, 4, 10}, {-3, -9, 0}}
```

The result I desire:

```
{{0.4147806779,-0.5068532453,-0.9609876522},{-1.140646864,1.151939194,1.034909779},{0.7258661863,-0.6450859486,-0.0739221271}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
Standardize@data
```

I'll assume you wanted something more general, so eg

```
MapThread[f, data]

(*{f[-4, -9, -3], f[-8, 4, -9], f[-8, 10, 0]}*)
```

Or if `f` only accepts a list as a parameter, why, wrap the arguments inside a list:

```
MapThread[
 f[{##}] &,
 data
 ]
```

Comment: To generalize your approach just span to the end.

`data == Array[d, {5, 7}];`

`Standardize@data[[All, 1 ;;]] == 
 Composition[Transpose, (Standardize /@ #) &, Transpose][data]`

`True`

Comment: This code `MapThread[f, data]` assume that function take several parameters. But function must take a `List`. But in particular `Standardize@data` You are right

Comment: well, here you go then

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
Thread[Standardize[data]]
```

**Edit after the question was changed and comment from acl:**

```
Standardize /@ Thread[data] // Transpose
```

Comment: but don't they say they want to map `f` over the columns? and doesn't `Thread[f[data]]` map `f` over rows?

Comment: @acl corrected this. It's not elegant.

Comment: @Karsten7 neither is mine, it seems the real problem they had wasn't the mapping bit.